# Can strings have escape sequences?

Tags: string, escaping

I am a novice programmer and I was wondering if strings can have escape sequences.

For example, is it possible to have a string look like

```
string s = "Hi\n\nI'm\n\nBob!\n\n";
```

So when I `cout << s`;

it'll look like

```
Hi

I'm

Bob!
```

? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: have you tried to test this?

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence#Programming_languages

> In many programming languages escape sequences are used in characters
>   and strings

And yes, your example would produce exactly that output